# remove check out check in and download functionality completely from site collection

Tags: client-object-model

Please help how to remove check out, check in and download functionality from the site collection so that it is not available for subsites too.
I don't have control over server hence I need to achieve through client object model.

Could you please suggest the right approach?

Thanks,

Comment: should you add more details to can help you faster , SharePoint version ,some screenshot of what you need to remove specifically !!